# how to control size of bubble in circle packing layout in d3

Tags: d3.js, circle-pack

in an animated circle packing d3 chart like this https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/54d01f118bc8d1f2c4ccd98235f33848

The bubble will always size to fill the rectangle drawing canvas. Is there a way to fix the size to be consistent such that I can make the bubble growing smaller? 
[image]

meanwhile because it'll scale up, even if passing in smaller value, the radius doesn't really get smaller.

for example: if data switched from [{"a",40}, {"b",50},{"c",60}] to 
 [{"a",4}, {"b",8},{"c",10}], ideally the circle get proportionally smaller.

how to control the scale? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`d3.pack()` has a method called `size`. According to the API:

> If size is specified, sets this pack layout’s size to the specified two-element array of numbers [width, height] and returns this pack layout.

So, for instance, in the bl.ocks you shared we can do...

```
.size([width/2, height/2])
```

... to reduce the packing area.

Have a look at this updated bl.ocks, I put a rectangle to show the reduced area and a lavender background in the SVG: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/de5ad7b9028289d290a62bc41f97f08b/880ec47cbfa236bb05e96b8e22dbe05e9bdf140d

**EDIT**

This is an edit addressing your edit, which is normally not a good practice in a S.O. answer, but I believe that this point is worth a clarification: changing the data doesn't matter!

In your edit you said that...

> if data switched from `[{"a",40}, {"b",50},{"c",60}]` to `[{"a",4}, {"b",8},{"c",10}]`, ideally the circles get proportionally smaller.

No, they won't! The layout gets the data and takes the maximum amount of the available space. For instance, even if you have an object like this:

```
[{name:"foo", size:1}]
```

This is what you'll have: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/0872af463ee0d786dc90f2d1361f241f/bd5357164708f09e2f130f510aea424809d9d1f1

Comment: thanks..I've edit the question for clarification. i think adjusting width and height kinda make the whole blob smaller but hard to calculate proportional size down to each circle.

Comment: The answer is still the one I explained here. The layout will take **any data** and fill the space specified in `size`.

Comment: if the 'a' element reduced by half and 'b' increase 10 folds, how would i know the overall size in terms of width and height. "The layout gets the data and takes the maximum amount of the available space" is the problem here. so i guess ur answer is saying scaled to proportion is impossible

Comment: @santoku yes, it's not possible without a hack, this is **not** how a circle packing works.